# I came across this Chord notation Em7(x7x070) then (x6x070 and finally (x5x070). Is anyone familiar with this?

Tags: guitar, chords

I found this in the song" Live like you were dying" by Tim McGraw. Can anyone help me on this? Chord notation  Em7(x7x070)  then (x6x070 and finally (x5x070). Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is tabulature-like notation of the chord written horizontally.

So, e.g. x7x070 means: don't play the bass E string, play A string on 7th fret, don't play D string, play open G string, B string on 7th fret and open treble E string.

Comment: One thing I might add or edit is I interpret the Xes to mean mute the string, or at lest muting is an alternative to not playing it.

Comment: @ToddWilcox thanks for the comment, though I don't believe the notation specifies how to avoid playing a note. If I played these chords with a pick, I would indeed mute both strings, but for extra clarity I would avoid hitting the bass E at all.

Answer (score 1):

(x7x070) then (x6x070 and finally (x5x070) => 6 strings EADGBE

There are for each chord 6 letters they refer to the 6 strings and the frets where they are touched:

x = don't play this string (mute)

7,0,6,5 etc. = assign the frets where these tones are: put your fingers here, albeit 0 means open string

You surely know the other chord notations like tab or chord shapes. s. guitar chord charts:

[charts](https://www.google.com/search?q=guitar%20chord%20chart&rlz=1C1CHBH_deCH697CH697&oq=guitar%20chord%20chart&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.6282j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

... and yes: these aren't barré chords, of course!

Answer (score 1):

It is another way of writing out chords specifically to be played on guitar. Standard tuning, left to right is bottom string to top. There are only four notes played in each chord - the 'X' shows that particuar string is either muted (if strumming) or simply not played (if finger-picking). The 'O' means that string is played open.

First chord is actually Em9, dropping to Em9maj7, to Em9 (inc.m7). Although I can't hear that F♯.